# How do I use the TWebOpenDialog in Delphi TMS Web Core?

Tags: delphi, fileopendialog, topendialog, opendialog, tms-web-core

I dropped the component onto the form and wrote the following code:

```
OpenDialog.Execute;
WebLabel1.Caption := OpenDialog.FileName;
```

It opens the `TWebOpenDialog`, but it doesn't put the `FileName` into the `Caption` of the label.

It seems like `OpenDialog.FileName` is empty, although when I `Execute` again, then the `OpenDialog.FileName` contains a `FileName`, but it's the `FileName` of the previous select.

How do you use the `TWebOpenDialog` in TMS Web Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TMS Web Core (JavaScript), each line is asynchronous and/or non-blocking.

So `Execute` doesn't wait for the user to select a file, it immediately runs the next line which is `WebLabel1.Caption := OpenDialog.FileName;` and thus the `FileName` is empty.

To overcome this, you need to use the `onChange` event on the `TWebOpenDialog` component. So you can add `WebLabel1.Caption := OpenDialog.Files[0].Name;` into the onChange event to get the `FileName`:

```
procedure TForm1.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenDialog.Execute;
end;

procedure TForm1.OpenDialogChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebLabel1.Caption := OpenDialog.Files[0].Name;
end;
```

Source: https://youtu.be/-tHOyl7NZho?si=cB1cs8MHeIKo3P_0